Meaning of *て*いませんか?
I know this kind of sounds useless, but the ませんか grammar does not sound correct here.
I was watching this podcast, and at 1:13, she tells the audience,

風邪をひいていませんか。

This...sounds weird. She says "the temp change is rather big, but will/have you caught a cold?," at least I think. But this is using both the ませんか ending and I believe 風邪をひいている, which means to have caught a cold. Is she saying "won't you have caught a cold?" How does the grammar work here? Is this is the same as 風邪をひきますか。 as 風邪をひきませんか sounds disrespectful, like "won't you catch a cold?" as an invitation.
Maybe I am wrong, but how should I parse this rather simple phrase?

When you say ～ていませんか, the expected/desirable answer can be yes or no depending on the context.

うちの子どもを見ていませんか。
Have you seen my child?
この漫画を持っていませんか。
Do you happen to have this manga?
田中さんを知っていませんか。
Don't you know Tanaka-san?
風邪をひいていませんか。
You haven't caught a cold, have you?
疲れていませんか。
Aren't you tired?
忘れていませんか？
Haven't you forgotten it?

Similarly, 風邪をひきませんか, without ている, is almost certainly an expression of concern ("Won't you catch a cold if you do that?"), expecting "no" as a desirable answer. Technically, it can be interpreted as an invitation ("Why don't you catch a cold?"), too, but this requires some unusual context, such as someone wanting to play hooky.

Hmm…so ていませんか means “have you…” or “do you…”? This differs from just ませんか, which is “won’t you…” Thus @weeab00 makes a point that 風邪をひいています is the same as ひいていませんか; as a matter of fact, because of the nature of ている in the resultative, all your examples make ていませんか and ていますか the same meaning-wise; ていませんか is more colloquial along with ていない. Is this the case?

I guess to include the “haven’t you” meaning, 行っていませんか would be “haven’t you went?” correct?

I think there is no difference between 風邪をひいていますか and 風邪をひいていませんか. They are simple yes/no questions. Answer 風邪をひいていませんか with はい if you are healthy or いいえ if you caught cold. Similarly, answer 風邪をひいていますか with いいえ if you are healthy or はい if you caught cold.

So 風邪をひいていますか means "Have you caught a cold" and 風邪をひいていませんか means "You have not caught a cold, right?"; this means the only difference is in how one responds to the question?

@BigRigz Yea I agree
